# Register Language Commands in Monaco

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

In the Monaco documentation, exact: in [CompletionItem](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.completionitem.html), there is a property called [command](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.completionitem.html#command)(Description: A command that should be run upon acceptance of this item.).
My question: where do i register these commands, if possible with a handler?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After asking through a github issue, this is the solution, see: [#1025](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1025)

```
(editor as any)._commandService.addCommand({ 
    id: "command-id", 
    handler: (_: any, ...args: any[]) => {
                    //DO WHAT NEEDED
        return null;
    },
});
```